# how to use call_user_func inside a cakephp model class?

Tags: php, cakephp, callback

I have the following function inside a cakephp model:

```
/**
 *
 * saveMany without MeioUpload validations
 *
 */
public function saveManyDataOnly($data) {
    // since creating records without files, 
    // we need to detach the behavior
    $this->Behaviors->unload('MeioUpload.MeioUpload');

    $result = $this->saveMany($data);

    $this->Behaviors->load('MeioUpload.MeioUpload');        

    return $result;
}
```

I also need the same thing for save, and saveAssociated.

By same thing, I mean I need to unload and then reload the Behavior after calling save and saveAssociated respectively.

I do not wish to use the callback beforeSave and afterSave.

> ***ADDED:***
>
> *I do not wish to override the save and saveAssociated methods as well.*
>
> *The reason is sometimes I want to use save, saveAssociated, saveMany with the behavior loaded.*
>
> the main reason why i want to **unload** the behavior sometimes is because the validations and the callbacks triggered by the behavior are **NOT desirable** for certain situations when i do a save, saveAssociated or saveMany

I could of course just simply write 2 more functions but I believe there should be a way to use call_user_func to accomplish the same aim without writing more code.

Help me understand how to write such code and how to call the new functions.

Comment: So, what is your problem? If you have the method that works for you why are you not happy? You can always call `call_user_func` or any other php function from any method in your model.

Comment: @bancer you are right that i have at least a working method. i am just trying to learn how to write a better solution and more elegant code.

Comment: 4 lines method seems to be short, clear and elegant for me. The key word is "clear". It is easy to read and understand. Take a look here - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/97912/how-do-you-define-elegant-code

Answer (score 0):

You can temporaly disable callback functions by passing 'callbacks' => false:

```
$this->save($data, array('validate' => true, 'callbacks' => false));
```

Comment: I do not wish to override because there are times i want to do a normal save with the behavior loaded. i also do not wish to use afterSave and beforeSave callbacks for the same reason.

Comment: I just update my answer, can you check if it's a good workaround for you?

Comment: the issue is that i need to unload the entire behavior for certain situations. not stop callbacks. the behavior has certain validations and callbacks i do not wish to trigger. so the best way is to unload it and then reload it back once i am done. and please do not tell me to set validate to false because that would also stop the validations of the model itself which I do not want.

Comment: similarly your solution would stop the callbacks of the model itself which i also do not want to happen.

Comment: I can't understand why you don't put unload behavior on beforeSave, and load on afterSave.
This way you can control wherever the behavior should be used or not.
Or you alredy have this callbacks doing something else?

Comment: because sometimes i do want the behavior to work when i run $this->save. The simplest way is to have a separate set of save for situations where i want to unload. but my question was to ask if there is a way for me to avoid having t o write a unload and load before and after the $this->save